# What is the proper way to use a package cache with MAAS or Juju?

Tags: juju, maas, apt-cacher-ng

I use an apt-cacher-ng server on one of the computers on my network.

I'm new trying to set up OpenStack, using Juju on MAAS. Is there a way to tell the machines Juju will be setting up to use this cache without it being used when they need to do HTTP for something other than packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can tell Juju to use any apt proxy you have set up:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/juju-misc#configure-proxy-access

Specifically you want to set `apt-http-proxy` and/or `apt-https-proxy`.